# InnoDB tables being made as MyISAM

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, phpmyadmin, innodb

I locally create my db tables using phpmyadmin. I set their engine to innoDB and create the foreign key relationships also using phpmyadmin. It all works locally.

However if I try to export those tables to the production site, the tables are created as MYISAM, and through the indexes on columns are created, they aren't linked as foreign keys to another table.

Any ideas why this would happen?

To export the tables, I just go to Export in PhpMyAdmin, this is an example of the query it gives me which I run on the production site:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `foo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `barId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `barId` (`barId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


ALTER TABLE `foo`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `foo_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`barId`) REFERENCES `barTable` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

This does create the table and makes an index on barId, but the table engine is myisam instead of inno, and there's no foreign key on barId refering to barTable.id

Comment: Does the prod DB support InnoDB?

Comment: +1 to @Dave Newton's answer. Type `SHOW ENGINES;` to see what database engines are supported at the remote server's end.

Comment: @vic yes, it supports InnoDb, i can manually switch it to inno db

Comment: To answer the second problem, MYISAM does not support foreign keys, which is why your ALTER statement does not create the FK. If your table was correctly getting created as INNODB, that FK creation would work. Next up-- in phpMyAdmin, will you go to the Variables tab on your prod server and see what it says for 'default storage engine' and 'storage engine'? I would also like you to take a look at the config.inc.php file in the phpMyAdmin directory and see if there is any option in there forcing MYISAM on table creation. To be continued...

Comment: ...continuation.

Lastly, I want you to run your CREATE from the mysql console and see if it produces any warnings. If it does, type SHOW WARNINGS to see them. You can also find these messages in wherever your logs are stored (found in /etc/my.cnf). My logs for example are in /var/log/mysqld.log.

Comment: Oh-- also, what is your version of MySQL on the production server?

Comment: @Vic storage eng: MYISAM, no entry for default storage eng.. I don't really have access to the config.php etc as its a client's server.. I can only access what i need but nothing else..

Answer (score 1):

From what you are saying, it looks like the production database server is ignoring the ENGINE=InnoDB clauses there.

Did you check to make sure that InnoDB is enabled on the production server?